# include client side js in express.js

Tags: express

I've build a new app with an express-generator so i've got public dir with javascripts i guess for a client side. But i can't get access to this files.
My app.js has for an absolute path

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

But when i put on my index.html page on the bottom of the body like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/main.js">
```

i've got an error inside a console with a 404 regarding to this script.

Comment: And `public/javascripts/main.js` exists?

Comment: yes. this all directories created express-generator

Comment: I created a project with express-generator and it works just fine for me. Did you change any parts of the created app that may have caused the routing to break? Also, I assume that you're requesting `index.html` from the running server (and not directly through the file system).

Answer (score 1):

you need to install stylus and nib npm modules

```
    var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib')

    function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib())
}

 app.use(stylus.middleware(
  { src: __dirname + '/public'
  , compile: compile
  }
))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am developing something similar. I have my javascript files inside js folder in public folder. This is my link to javascript and I am not getting any error:

```
<script src="js/options.js"></script>
```

I think you needed to remove a common slash in "src" tag or properly close the "script"

Comment: does not work for me. There should be an idea why they create public directory for all of this